# Composer user version or dev

Tags: version, composer-php

I im definining a package in my composer. The latest package version has a bug that is solved in the dev release. I want to use the dev branch until the new release is released.

Package current version 
- 7.1.4

So I want to use version 7.1.5 or higher (which isn't released yet) and until then dev.

How would I put this in my composer.json ?

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `@dev` flag combined with the `7.1.x` patch level version range, while waiting for the `v7.1.5` (tag) release: `7.1.x-dev`.

```
{
    "require": {
        "vendor/package": "7.1.*@dev"
    }
}
```

Or you could skip the range and just use `dev-master` for a while and drop it, when the next version is out.

Comment: Don't use `dev-master`. Other packages you might use may depend on a version 7.1 to be present. That information gets lost if you switch to `dev-master`. Additionally, the master branch need not be the branch where the fix is present.